# Split very large CSV file to Smaller files on the basis of size

Tags: csv, split, large-files

I have large 133GB CSV file in my with header in my local system .I want to split this file in 5 parts and each file should contain the header.

I have tried doing it through git bash command
split -b size largefile.csv

But this is now working properly

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish splitting the CSV with common Unix line-processing tools, at least not easily.

I recommend a CSV-aware tool that has some facility for letting you specify how many files or how many rows-per-file you want to end up with:

- [miller's split command](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/6.8.0/reference-verbs/index.html#split) lets you specify the max number of rows perfile, or set the number of files (but Round Robin, see the examples)
- [GoCSV's split command](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#split) lets you specify the max number of rows per file

I like GoCSV so I'll show how to accomplish what I think you want with its split command:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

fname=input.csv

# Get number of rows in CSV
nrows=$(gocsv nrow $fname) || exit 1

# Get desired number of files
printf "%s" "Number of split CSVs: "
read nfiles

# Calculate rows per file
nRowsPerFile=$(( (nrows / nfiles) + 1 ))
echo "Will split $fname with $nrows rows into $nfiles files, each with a max of $nRowsPerFile rows"

# Remove any previous splits, split to files starting with name "split"
rm split-*.csv
gocsv split -filename-base split -max-rows $nRowsPerFile $fname || exit 1

# Check work
echo ""
ls split-*.csv | while read CSV; do 
    nrows=$(gocsv nrow "$CSV") || exit 1
    echo "$CSV $nrows"
done
```

I generated a CSV with random data that has 1_234_567 rows (about 46 MB).  When I run with the following inputs I get:

- 1 split file:

  ```
  Number of split CSVs: 1
  Will split input.csv with 1234567 rows into 1 files, each with a max of 1234568 rows
  split-1.csv 1234567
  ```
- 3 split files:

  ```
  Number of split CSVs: 3
  Will split input.csv with 1234567 rows into 3 files, each with a max of 411523 rows
  split-1.csv 411523
  split-2.csv 411523
  split-3.csv 411521
  ```
- 5 split files:

  ```
  Number of split CSVs: 5
  Will split input.csv with 1234567 rows into 5 files, each with a max of 246914 rows
  split-1.csv 246914
  split-2.csv 246914
  split-3.csv 246914
  split-4.csv 246914
  split-5.csv 246911
  ```